# How to vectorize a piecewise periodic function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I've noticed that matlab builtin functions can handle either scalar or vector parameters.  Example:

```
sin(pi/2)
ans =
     1

sin([0:pi/5:pi])
ans =
         0    0.5878    0.9511    0.9511    0.5878    0.0000
```

If I write my own function, for example, a piecewise periodic function:

```
function v = foo(t)
t = mod( t, 2 ) ;

if ( t < 0.1 )
   v = 0 ;
elseif ( t < 0.2 )
   v = 10 * t - 1 ;
else
   v = 1 ;
end
```

I can call this on individual values:

```
[foo(0.1) foo(0.15) foo(0.2)]
ans =
         0    0.5000    1.0000
```

however, if the input for the function is a vector, it is not auto-vectorized like the builtin function:

```
foo([0.1:0.05:0.2])
ans =
     1
```

Is there a syntax that can be used in the definition of the function that indicates that if a vector is provided, a vector should be produced?  Or do builtin functions like sin, cos, ... check for the types of their input, and if the input is a vector produce the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your syntax slightly to be able to handle data of any size. I typically use logical filters to vectorise if-statements, as you're trying to do:

```
function v = foo(t)

v = zeros(size(t));
t = mod( t, 2 ) ;

filt1 = t<0.1;
filt2 = ~filt1 & t<0.2;
filt3 = ~filt1 & ~filt2;

v(filt1) = 0;
v(filt2) = 10*t(filt2)-1;
v(filt3) = 1;
```

In this code, we've got three logical filters. The first picks out all elements such that `t<0.1`. The second picks out all of the elements such that `t<0.2` that weren't in the first filter. The final filter gets everything else.

We then use this to set the vector `v`. We set every element of `v` that matches the first filter to `0`. We set everything in `v` which matches the second filter to `10*t-1`. We set every element of `v` which matches the third filter to `1`.

For a more comprehensive coverage of vectorisation, check the [MATLAB help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) on it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach that minimizes the number of operations is:

```
function v = foo(t)
t = mod(t, 2);
v = ones(size(t)) .* (t > 0.1);
v(t < 0.2) = 10*t(t < 0.2) - 1;
end
```

If the vectors are large, it might be faster to do `ind = t < 0.2`, and use that in the last line. That way you only search through the array once. Also, the multiplication might be substituted by an extra line with logical indices.

Answer (score 0):

I repeatedly hit the same problem, thus I was looking for a more generic solution and came up with this:

```
%your function definition
c={@(t)(mod(t,2))<0.1,0,...
@(t)(mod(t,2))<0.2,@(t)(10 * t - 1),...
true,1};
%call pw which returns the function
foo=pw(c{:});
%example evaluation
foo([0.1:0.05:0.2])
```

Now the code for pw

```
function f=pw(varargin)
for ip=1:numel(varargin)
    switch class(varargin{ip})
        case {'double','logical'}
            varargin{ip}=@(x)(repmat(varargin{ip},size(x)));
        case 'function_handle'
            %do nothing
        otherwise
            error('wrong input class')
    end
end
c=struct('cnd',varargin(1:2:end),'fcn',varargin(2:2:end));
f=@(x)pweval(x,c);

end

function y=pweval(x,p)
todo=true(size(x));
y=x.*0;
for segment=1:numel(p)
    mask=todo;
    mask(mask)=logical(p(segment).cnd(x(mask)));
    y(mask)=p(segment).fcn(x(mask));
    todo(mask)=false;
end
assert(~any(todo));
end
```