# Using MATLAB integral with anonymous functions

Tags: matlab, math

I'm trying to use the MATLAB `integral()` function to integrate along a single parameter of a piecewise linear function that represents a time-varying value.

I would like to define an anonymous function based on the original function:

```
t1 = 1;
t2 = 2;
t3 = 4;
t4 = 5;

a0 = 1;
a1 = 2;

f = @(x) accel_profile(t1,t2,t3,t4,a0,a1,x);
```

and here is the accel_profile.m:

```
function value = accel_profile(t1,t2,t3,t4,a0,a1, t)

if t <= t1
    value = a0;
    return
elseif (t <= t2)
    value = ((t-t1)/(t2-t1)) * (a1-a0) + a0;
    return
elseif (t <= t3)
    value = a1;
    return
elseif (t <= t4)
    value = ((t-t3)/(t4-t3)) * (a0-a1) + a1;
    return
else
    value = a0;
    return
end
```

The problem is that when I exercise the following script:

```
t_list = 0:0.1:6;
q = zeros(1,length(t_list))
for i = 1:length(t_list)
    q(i) = integral(f,0,t_list(i));
end

plot(t_list, q)
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
Error using integralCalc/finalInputChecks (line 515)
Output of the function must be the same size as the input. If FUN is an array-valued integrand, set
the 'ArrayValued' option to true.
Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 315)
                finalInputChecks(x,fx);
Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);
Error in integralCalc (line 75)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);
Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct); 
515             error(message('MATLAB:integral:FxNotSameSizeAsX'));
```

I'm running MATLAB 2015b on Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `integral` uses vectorized arguments for your function, but your function does not support it.

The relevant part from the documentation:

> For scalar-valued problems, the function y = fun(x) must accept a vector argument, x, and return a vector result, y. This generally means that fun must use array operators instead of matrix operators. For example, use .* (times) rather than * (mtimes). If you set the 'ArrayValued' option to true, then fun must accept a scalar and return an array of fixed size.

[Reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html)

This means integral will call your function `f` with arguments like `f([1,2,3])` and expects a list with `[f(1),f(2),f(3)]`

The general techniques [to vectorize a piecewise defined function are explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097861/how-to-vectorize-a-piecewise-periodic-function-in-matlab)

Comment: Aww, beat me to it:( It should also work to set `'ArrayValued'` to true: then the function is only called with scalar arguments. Then you don't need to vectorize (but you should; that would be much faster).

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I thought the option is supposed for functions returning vectors, I did not conciser using it here. My matlab version is to old to have that option, if it really solves it please write an answer.

Comment: Setting 'ArrayValued' to 'true' did the trick, thanks!  I read that and thought that was only for functions returning array values, so my bad!

Comment: Indeed, Daniel, it works, I've just checked. And thanks, but I don't think it's necessary to add a new answer just because of this:) Feel free to add it to your own for completeness. [Here's the result, btw](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zQnvr.png). It's *meant* for array-valued functions, but under the hood it just avoids using vector-valued input for speedup.