# How do I write this double integral function in MATLAB and create it as a separate function file?

Tags: matlab

This is the double integral [Double integral snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCmgv.png)

This is so far what I've done [Double integral attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyCs3.png)

Seems like such a simple thing. I know. I have bad teachers. Thanks for the help!
P.S the version I'm using R2013a

**Edit: Let me just copy and paste the code

```
function [] = rho_s_fun()
%UNTITLED4 Summary of this function goes here
% Amistupid.docx
%   Detailed explanation goes here
    fun =@(x,y) x*y*(x^2+y^2+25)^3/2;
    Q = integral2(fun,0,0,1,1);

end
```

the error is:

```
>> rho_s_fun
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in rho_s_fun>@(x,y)x*y*(x^2+y^2+25)^3/2 (line
5)
    fun =@(x,y) x*y*(x^2+y^2+25)^3/2;

Error in integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 238)
            Z1 = FUN(X(VTSTIDX),Y(VTSTIDX)); NFE =
            NFE + 1;

Error in integral2Calc>integral2t (line 56)
[Qsub,esub] = tensor(thetaL,thetaR,phiB,phiT);

Error in integral2Calc (line 10)
    [q,errbnd] =
    integral2t(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);
    
Error in integral2 (line 107)
    Q =
    integral2Calc(fun,xmin,xmax,yminfun,ymaxfun,opstruct);
    
Error in rho_s_fun (line 6)
    Q = integral2(fun,0,0,1,1);
```

The main code where I'm trying to link the double integral(not sure if link is the proper word) is:

```
clear
format short

%The following part is for part (a)
dx = input('Enter the integration increment dx... \n >');
dy = input('Enter the integration increment dy... \n >');
total_charge=0;
for x=0:dx:1, 
for y=0:dy:1,
total_charge=rho_s_fun(x,y)*dx*dy+total_charge;
end
end
disp(sprintf('The total charge computed by manual double'));
disp(sprintf(' integration is %d nC',total_charge));
total_charge=dblquad(@rho_s_fun, 0, 1, 0, 1);
disp(sprintf('The total charge computed by the functional'))
disp(sprintf(' double integration is %d n',total_charge))

%The following for part (b)
Etotal=0;
for x=0:dx:1,
for y=0:dx:1,
rminusrprime=[-x -y 5];
numerator=rho_s_fun(x,y)*1e-9*dx*dy*rminusrprime;
denominator=4*pi*1e-9/(36*pi)*norm(rminusrprime)^3;
Etotal=Etotral+numerator/denominator;
end
end
disp(sprintf('The electric field computed by manual double'));
disp(sprintf(' integration is (%d, %d, %d) V/m',... 
    Etotal(1), Etotal(2), Etotal(1)))
```

Comment: Please no images of code. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode for more information.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE I don’t find the “i downvoted because” website helpful. Instead use this link: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Sam, please read the link in this comment instead.

Comment: Sam, also describe why your code is not suitable. Do you get an error? Do you get the wrong result? Do you not get any result? Knowing what the problem is with your attempt will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: I've copied and pasted the code, thanks for the information

Comment: The answer here should solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35004410/7328782

Comment: It's looking like french to me :'(