# How to write indicator function in matlab

Tags: matlab, intervals

I am a new user of matlab and I want to tackle the following problem:

I want to construct a piecewise constant function `f`. `f` should be an anonymous function like `f=@(t)1[0,0.25)(t)`. However, the number of intervals for the piecewise constant function is not fixed in general. Instead, the piecewise interval depends on users input.

For example, if one enters 4, the piecewise interval becomes

> [0,0.25), [0.25,0.5), [0.5,0.75) and [0.75,1)

then

> f=@(t)a1*1[0,0.25)(t)+a2*[0.25,0.5)(t)+a3*1[0.5,0.75)(t)+a4*1[0.75,1)(t);

While if one enters 5, the piecewise interval becomes

> [0,0.2), [0.2,0.4), [0.4,0.6), [0.6,0.8) and [0.8,1)

Are there any good ways to tackle the problem?

Comment: Note that any situation where you use an anonymous function, you can also use a normal Matlab function and the @ operator to get a function handle. Eg. `@sum` would be a function handle to the function `sum`.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to use @sum? When I try in matlab, it gives error message that I cannot do it in this way.

Comment: When you do `f = @(x) x.^2` you assign to the variable `f` a function handle to a function which computes `x.^2`. You could also create a file `myfunction.m` with the text `function result = myfunction(x) ... result = x.^2` and then assign `f = @myfunction` In the second case, `f` would also be assigned a function handle to a function which computes `x.^2`.

Comment: Execute `f = @sum` and then `sum(x)` and `f(x)` will return the same result (it's kinda like function pointers in the programming language `c`). If you're new to Matlab or programming, this might be confusing and you should not worry about it and forget I ever mentioned it.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097861/how-to-vectorize-a-piecewise-periodic-function-in-matlab/35046524

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the weights a1,...,ak are already defined, you can use the following approach:

```
%defines weight vector. for example: a1=1, a2=2, a3=3, a4=4,a5=5
A = 1:5;  
%defines a range vector
ranges = [0:(1/length(A)):1,inf];
%The padding is for handling cases where t<0 or t>=1
APadded = [0,A,0];
%define f
f=@(t)APadded(find(t<ranges,1,'first'))
```

Result:

```
f(0.1) = 1
f(0.3) = 2
f(0.5) = 3
f(0.7) = 4
f(0.9) = 5
f(-0.1) = f(1.1) = 0;
```