# Can anyone tell me how to write indicator function for vector input in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am a new user of matlab and stackoverflow. I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349914/how-to-write-indicator-function-in-matlab/37350742#37350742) about how to write indicator function f, the question was as follow:

"f should be an anonymous function like f=@(t)1[0,0.25)(t). However, the number of intervals for the piecewise constant function is not fixed in general. Instead, the piecewise interval depends on users input."

I am glad that some users answered my question. 
The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37350742/2955997) answered is as follow:

```
%defines weight vector. for example: a1=1, a2=2, a3=3, a4=4,a5=5
A = 1:5;  
%defines a range vector
ranges = [0:(1/length(A)):1,inf];

%The padding is for handling cases where t<0 or t>=1

APadded = [0,A,0]; 
f=@*(t)APadded(find(t < ranges,1,'first'));

Result
f(0.1) = 1, f(0.3) = 2, f(0.5) = 3, f(0.7) = 4, f(0.9) = 5, f(-0.1) = f(1.1) = 0;
```

I want to extend the codes a little bit. For example, if I define @(X)sun(X), when the input of X is a vector, it gives output to be a vector. However, the above solution for indicator result does not. One can try f([0.1 0.3 0.5 0.7 0.9]) which does not give 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

How to solve this problem so that even if the input is a vector, it will give correct result?

Answer (score 0):

Use Matlab's arrayfun function on the created f function:

```
f2=@(t)arrayfun(f,t);
```

Result:

```
f2([-0.1, 0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9,1.1])

ans =

 0     1     2     3     4     5     0
```

Full code example:

```
%defines weight vector. for example: a1=1, a2=2, a3=3, a4=4,a5=5 
A = 1:5;
%defines a range vector
ranges = [0:(1/length(A)):1,inf];

%The padding is for handling cases where t<0 or t>=1
APadded = [0,A,0]; 
fTemp=@(t)APadded(find(t < ranges,1,'first'));
f=@(t)arrayfun(fTemp,t);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to approach the other users?