# How can I create a discontinuous function that is not a symbolic one in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, ode

[image]

How do I create the function `P(t)` with `t` as a vector? I tried to create it using the function `piecewise()` but is it possible to create it as a numeric vector so that further calculations can be made?

Comment: I think you can use a simple if in your function, and it should work even on a vector...

Comment: I guess this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097861/how-to-vectorize-a-piecewise-periodic-function-in-matlab

Comment: What tools are you trying to use? `P(t)=min(2,max(0,t))*10` should work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can first define a function `f()` and then vectorize it via `arrayfun()`

```
function pt = f(t)
  if t <= 2
    pt = 10*t;
  else
    pt = 20;
  end
end

P = @(t) arrayfun(@f,t);
```

or a more elegant one (similar to the comments by @Lutz Lehmann under your post)

```
P = @(t) min(20,max(0,t)*10)
```

then you can see

```
>> P(0:25)
ans =

 Columns 1 through 20:

    0   10   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20

 Columns 21 through 26:

   20   20   20   20   20   20
```